Exact location in Josephus where it is stated that the Maccabean War began when they slaughtered a Hellenized Jew
Can anybody pinpoint the book and the paragraphs? Thanks.

Not sure if the guy they killed was a Hellenized Jew, but here is the source. Wars of the Jews, Book 1

